# How do I find strings to be localized in my C# project?

Tags: c#, regex, visual-studio

I'm trying to write a regex to be used within Visual Studio or an external program without success. What I want that expression to do is:

- Match rows containing quoted text like `var myString = "This shall be moved out of here"`
- Do not match rows within comments like `///<summary>This method has some "quoted text"</summary>` or `//This is "just a comment"`, which may have tabs at their beginning due to indentation.

From within Visual Studio I'm able to include files by extension, say `*.cs`, so I can easily skip xml files and so on. I'm not able to exclude those `*.Designer.cs` files however, so I found that [FileSeek](http://www.fileseek.ca/) does a pretty good job being able to include and exclude files by extension or regex; anyway if there's a way to accomplish the same from VS, that would be great.

Any help would be much appreciated, thank you.

Comment: A few approaches 1) First run regexes that remove all comments comments, followed by string parsing 2) Write a basic parser which understands the rules for comments and strings 3) Build something on Roslyn, which understands C# syntax and semantic.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're end goal is, but Resharper can do this: http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/internationalization.html

Comment: Just some side notes: If you need this to work with any valid code, you'll also need to consider `/**/` comments, `/**/` multline comments, and general multiline statements. Or, like @CodesInChaos said, use something Roslyn based. Then you're working with the code rather than a flat text file.

Answer (score 0):

The below regex would match all the lines that won't start with `//`  and contains `"` present inside that.

```
^(?!\s*\/\/).*(?=\").*$
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/nP6gQ1)

Comment: The problem is that there are two comment styles `//` and `/*` and two string styles (normal and verbatim) with non trivial escaping rules. Verbatim strings can even span multiple lines.

Comment: then this regex would be helpful. `^(?!\/\/|\/\*).*(?=\").*$`

Comment: I don't usually use `/*` notation so it's not a big deal. Problem here is that this regex also includes lines starting with any space or tab followed by `//` (indented)

Comment: Seems that `^(?!\s*\/\/).*(?=\").*$` does the job

Comment: @CodesInChaos yes it won't work for multiline comments. This would match single line `//` or `///` or `/*` comments.`^(?!\s*\/\/|\/\*).*(?=\").*$`